# Why mybatis need @Param?

Tags: mybatis

```
User selectUser(@param(“name”)String name,@param(“password”)String password);

<select id=" selectUser" resultMap="BaseResultMap">  
   select  *  from user  where user_name = #{name} and user_password=#{password} 
</select>
```

Like this code, mybatis can use reflection to get variable name, variables have different name, can replace `@param(“XXX”)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the actual question:

By default, the parameter names of methods are NOT part of the bytecode. So what you propose does not work by default.

MyBatis uses generic names for parameters for which it can't determine the name:

> [...] they will be named by the literal "param" followed by their position in the parameter list by default, for example: #{param1}, #{param2} etc. If you wish to change the name of the parameters (multiple only), then you can use the @Param("paramName") annotation on the parameter.

So if you use those names in your SQL code things should work fine.

If you specify the `-parameters` compiler flag for javac it will indeed include the names of method parameters and the approach you suggested works in principle. I have seen a tutorial that claimed MyBatis will use those, although the reference documentation doesn't seem to mention it. You might give that a try.